# How to keep my Android phone asleep until I press the power button

Tags: battery-life, android-12, sleep

When I am done with doing something on my Android phone, I put it asleep with the Power Button. I expect it to stay asleep until I press Power again, or perhaps until a phone call comes in. This is to minimize draining the battery.

However, the phone wakes up when putting it away, e.g. in my trouser bag. After several seconds the screen goes dark again. But why? Is this a 'feature'?

When walking in the dark, the phone backlight will shine through my clothes.

Is it possible to turn this 'feature' off?

I might be old fashioned, wanting to be in control in turning this thing on and off when I, the owner, want this.

This behaviour happened with my previous phone, Motorola Moto, with android 11, and with my current Moto E32s with Android 12.

Comment: Does your Settings app have an option which is something like "Lift to wake up" or "Lift to check phone"? If yes, disable it and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudo's to
@Firelord: disabling Lift To Wake was very important, thanks!

In the same settings page I found Peek Display to be somewhat important, to keep the phone asleep. Peek shows the time on a black screen in small font every once in a while during sleep.

Both settings can be found by searching Settings for Lift, or by going to Settings, Display, Advanced.